# How to get database other fields on change even of dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Below are my code parts javascript, main.php and getparty.php

1) getparty.php code is as follow called from javascript to take details
   from party table on change of dropdown value of party from main.php

```
<?php
    $q = intval($_GET['q']);
    include "dbc.php";
    $sql= mysql_query("Select a.pcode,a.pname,a.discperc,a.delvterm from PARTY a where a.pcode='$q'") or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $pcode=$row['pcode'];
    $ppname=$row['pname'];
    $pdiscperc=$row['discperc'];
?>

main.php ... it is my main form to display main form for user to enter
```

`<tr>
        <td><font face="verdana" size="2" color="#000000">Party</font></td>
        <td>
           <?php
                    <td align="left" >
                       <?php
                          $sql="UPDATE PARTY set repo_flag=0 ";
                          if (!mysql_query($sql,$conn))
                          {
                          die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
                          }
                          if ($ppname!="")
                          {
                          $sql="UPDATE PARTY set repo_flag=1 where pname='$ppname' ";
                          }
                          if (!mysql_query($sql,$conn)) 
                          {
                          die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
                          }
                       $dropdown = "<select id='pname' name='pname' style='width:275px' onchange='showparty(this.value)' value='<?php echo $ppname; ?>' >";
                       $query1 = "select pcode,pname from PARTY order by repo_flag DESC ";
                       $get=mysql_query($query1);
                       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($get))
                       {
                       $dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$row['pcode']}'>{$row['pname']}</option>";
                       }
                       $dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";
                       echo $dropdown;
                       ?>
           ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" maxlength="3" size="3" name="txtdiscperc"  value="<?php echo $pdiscperc; ?>"/></td>
    </tr>`

```
Javascript .. This is called to take value of party when dropdown 
combo changes

<script>
function showparty(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtpartyname").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtpartyname").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getparty.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>

I am not getting value of Discount % in main.php, and some other fields       also I want to get from party table which I can write code when above discount % gets properly. How can I
```

Comment: Your line of code `$dropdown = "<select id='pname' name='pname' style='width:275px' onchange='showparty(this.value)' value='<?php echo $ppname; ?>' >";` looks incorrect - is it really like that?

The `value='<?php echo $ppname; ?>'` bit should probably just be `value='$ppname' ` otherwise those PHP tags will actually be printed out in your HTML.

Comment: code of drop down is part, not all code

Comment: check the HTML actually generated for your dropdown menu, you may see <?php tags in the HTML which are causing the problem

Comment: I updated total drop down code in above part

Comment: It is still messed up in the same way I described to you twice already (php tags that will be outputted to the page) - if you can't understand what I've already suggested then I really can't help

Comment: yes sir in value it was double <?php which I rectified thanks